# Loop, reset and raise numbers

Tags: java

In java, Is there a way to loop through each time a number is greater than another number then reset the first number to 0, and raise the 2nd number by a set value then do it all over again once the first number gets higher than the 2nd number?

```
int number1 = 6517253;
int number2 = 7195629;
```

Comment: The only num being reset to 0 is number1?

Comment: I really don't understand what's being asked here. Do you just want a `for` loop?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, outside of spinning a few thousand CPU cycles?  Could you give some context?

Comment: I'm basically setting a progression meter, and once progression has become greater than the target, it resets the meter and sets a higher target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the following code...

```
int number1 = 6517253;
int number2 = 7195629;
int setValue = 12345; // Whatever the "set value" needs to be
boolean continueLooping = true;

while (continueLooping) {
    for (int i = number1; i <= number2; i++)
        doSomething();
    number1 = 0;
    number2 += setValue;
    if (<some-condition>)
        continueLooping = false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm yes, this actually looks like what I am trying. I've had for loops, while loops, if statements in my head all day

Comment: @MyOwnHarem : I've edited my code example to allow a way of breaking out of the `while` loop. Just replace `<some-condition>` with whatever you want to test for in order to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (number1 <= number2)
{
    number1 = number1 + setNumber;
}
number1 = 0;
```

If this is what you mean. Your question is a little confusing for me but this will loop through and increment number2 by the setNumber variable value until number1 is greater than number2. It then resets number1 to 0. Let me know if you are looking for something else. This isn't really how I read the question but the way I read it didn't make sense

Comment: Sorry for not making sense =o(

I couldn't really figure out how to actually say what I wanted, that was the best I could think of.

Comment: No problem, I can understand that. I was just trying to give the best help I could with what I was reading. I'm glad you got it figured out but infinite loops are rarely a good idea :)

Comment: I don't know if it's actually figured out yet, and I don't really want it to be infinite, I basically only want it to loop back and start over again each time number1 > number2, but If I use an if statement it only resets it once.

Comment: I understand that. It sounds like you definitely need a loop. I just think it should end at some point. But how do you want to increment the first number? You have to do that or it will always be 0 after you reset it to 0.